# Browser addon that aids avoiding sites with excessive use of third party cookies, tracking etc

Tags: web-browser, privacy, plug-in, cookies

Being not happy with the privacy-unfriendly status-quo where I "need to" share data just because I want to view online-content (legitimate consent, ...) I am wondering whether there is a browser extension that aids identifying such websites and spams me with warnings, which could help me avoid these sites in the future even better.
I tend to simply decline all cookies I can, but I would prefer an even more drastic solution and not give those sites a view anymore, at all.

Would there even be an extension that could do this on mouse-hover over a URL/link?
I guess I need not say the addon should be for Firefox or similarly privacy-friendly browsers; don't answer for Edge/Chrome-only addons ;)

(And what add-ons could also be interesting for a privacy-concerned person?)

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever used [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/ublock-origin/) and its (unfortunately no longer developed) companion [uMatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/umatrix/)? I cannot imagine browsing without them. Depending how strict you set them, they can block everything until you decide, per website or globally, to set it free. e.g. no Javascript, etc. uBlock Origin can also "suppress" those "consent banners". For me, these two are the "defense base" – plus [Cookie Autodelete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-autodelete/).

- **uMatrix:** as the name suggests, gives you a "matrix" to control elements like cookies, css, media, scripts and from which sites you allow them for a given site (i.e. never load Google Analytics on any site)
- **uBlock:** blocks unwanted domains and elements on a page
- **Cookie Autodelete:** unless you specify otherwise, cokkies for a site are deleted seconds after you close the last tab having a page of that site open.

Further recommended:

- [LocalCDN](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/localcdn-fork-of-decentraleyes/) to avoid contacting CDNs for all kinds of resources (like JQuery, WebFonts etc). The addon rather supplies them locally and injects the to the sites asking for those resources.
- [HTTPS Everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/https-everywhere/) to prevent information leaing via insecure network connections.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation; I already use uBlock, but that mainly addresses advertises and does not scale for more restrictive settings. I have not yet tried out uMatrix, LocalCDN and Cookie Autodelete, but will. HTTPS Everywhere is somewhat not related to the question, my browser handles that anyway ;-)
Sadly, these extensions do not address the issue with memorizing which websites are 'bad' (privacy-wise), and which not. I thought of something like a traffic light that tells me I should simply avoid the site at all, so I learn to not use them instead of mitigating their tracking. ;)

Comment: I think the answer is a great first-aid-kit, but I leave the question open as I feel it is still lacking some even more restrictive tools I would love to learn about :-)

Comment: Sure leave it open! We only close questions if they're off-topic (or spam). Besides, uBlock can do much more than just blocking ads. There are some comprehensive guides around you might wish to check. And as for HTTPS: I doubt your browser handles that completely if the site in question does not tell it's also available via HTTPS (and there are some such out there still). // I know no solution for that "traffic light"; I usually close tabs if they stay empty, especially when uBlock/uMatrix show multi-digit numbers #D

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have tried uMatrix for a day now and am quite fond of it. I will also check out for additional settings. As mentioned, I would also love to hear of addons that additionally advise against using sites that unreasonably track users even if blocking the tracking does not break the site's functionality, which would be the situation where uBlock/uMatrix do a good job

Answer (score 0):

[Izzy is completely right](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/80477/76723), uBlock Origin is the way to go, especially with a well tailored [set of rules](https://filterlists.com/)

In the past I used [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/) which was specifically for getting an understanding of the backends used. However I now understand it is discouraged because of it's own built in tracking.

There is also an interesting "If you can't fight them, drown them" approach with [adNauseam](https://adnauseam.io/) and [TrackMeNot](http://trackmenot.io/), two very interesting projects.

> NOTE: see [Izzy's comment](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/80473/browser-addon-that-aids-avoiding-sites-with-excessive-use-of-third-party-cookies#comment98500_80486) for some concerns around these.

Comment: Note that Ghostery is discouraged for use by many privacy experts as they found it tracking itself (see e.g. [here](https://www.kuketz-blog.de/?s=ghostery) in German). Unfortunately, adNauseam [has its risks as well](https://www.kuketz-blog.de/adnauseam-adblocker-besser-nicht-nutzen/) (profiling by IP and UserAgent, which is transferred with every request).

Comment: I agree that uBlock origin is the way to go, I was voicing out additional options, and I wasn't aware of Ghostery, I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: No offense meant – I was just adding the concerns. Be welcome to include them directly with your answer and we clean up comments. It's especially hard to find trustable addons in this area, so it's good to also have the culprits pointed out. Especially with addons often recommended wrongly due to lack of background (and I must admit having used Ghostery too, 10+ years ago. I stopped that when they moved configuration dialogs and all to the cloud, as that's not my idea of privacy).

Comment: Thank you very much for mentioning the addons and also pointing out their own tracking/profiling (which sounds like shifting trust from one provider to the other). It's still good to have them listed here this way :)